# Spring cloud config serving plain text with subfolder

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have this file structure:

```
conf-repo:
  templates:
    examples:
      hello.ftl
```

I  want get this file from config server as raw text. In documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text I not found how can use subfolders.

When I tried this request: GET http://localhost:8888/config-server/my-app/default/templates/examples/hello.ftl?useDefaultLabel, I got 404 error.

How I can get this file using subfolders?

Comment: Try with a label? default/{main|master}/templates

Comment: I don't want use label. I want use default label! Why does the client need to know which branch is used on the server when accessing it? Let him use the default branch! Only the config server should know the branch!